# Order of growth of the code below

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment as a function of N? ￼

```
int sum = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i*i < N; i++) 
   for (int j = 0; j*j < 4*N; j++) 
       for (int k = 0; k < N*N; k++) 
           sum++;
```

Comment: It seems to be java for me, so I added the tag. If you had another language in mind, please retag.

Comment: This looks like homework.

Answer (score 3):

1. outer loop runs until `i*i >= N`, that means it runs total of
   `sqrt(N)` times.
2. For each iteration of outer loop, inner loop runs until `j*j >= 4*N`, similarly that means it runs `sqrt(4N) = 2sqrt(N)` times.
3. For each iteration of middle loop, inner loop runs until `k>=N*N`, this means `N^2` iterations.
4. Increasing sum is done in constant time.

Multiply the above because you do (3) for each iteration of (2), and (2) for each iteration of (1), and you get `sqrt(N)*2sqrt(N)*N^2 = 2N^3`, which is in `O(N^3)`